# Different results from the same function when loaded in global environment vs in a package

Tags: r, devtools

### Problem

I am developing a simple package to learn `R` package development using this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r3yklH7Gk1s). For this purpose, I wrote a function and then tried it out within the global environment, and then provided it in the package. But I get different results while running the function in these two contexts.

### Function

```
what_time <- function(language = "english") {

  if (!language %in% c("urdu", "english")) {
    stop("Either choose english or urdu as a language.")
  }

  time <- format(Sys.time(), "%H:%M")

  if (language == "urdu") {

    paste(time, "وقت ھوا ہے")

    } else if (language == "english"){

      sprintf("It is %s now!", time)
  }


}
```

#### Running the function in the global environment:

I created the above function definition in `R` console and then run the function:

```
what_time("urdu")
[1] "08:47 وقت ھوا ہے"
```

#### Running the function after loading the package:

Then I restarted the R session and did the following:

```
devtools::load_all()
i Loading umair
what_time("urdu")
[1] "08:47 <U+0648><U+0642><U+062A> <U+06BE><U+0648><U+0627> <U+06C1><U+06D2>"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at the output of `Sys.getlocale()` in both instances.  It likely produces different output.  Note that one normally does this using `match.arg` like this: `what_time <- function(language = c("english", "urdu")) {
  language <- match.arg(language);
  time <- format(Sys.time(), "%H:%M");
  if (language == "urdu") {
    paste(time, "وقت ھوا ہے")
  } else sprintf("It is %s now!", time)
}`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, I tried your function but still get the same result. I think it has to do with the package development. It does not like non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Please expand on how you created the package. The tutorial is 1 hour and 50 minutes long; we're not going to go through all of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that 'special characters' are not supported in your self-made package. Check the values of `Encoding` in your package's DESCRIPTION file, and of `Sys.getlocale()`, `Sys.getenv('LANG')`, and `Sys.getenv('LC_CTYPE')` in your R session.

Which language you have there shouldn't matter much, but it should be a UTF-8 variant.

I am having no problems to produce the correct output on my own machine with the following settings:

**File 'testpackage/DESCRIPTION'**

```
...
Encoding: UTF-8
...
```

**R(Studio) session**

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8"

> Sys.getenv('LANG')
[1] "en_US.UTF-8"

> Sys.getenv('LC_CTYPE')
[1] "en_US.UTF-8"
```

> *To modify these settings:*
>
> ```
> Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", 'en_EN.UTF-8')
> Sys.setenv("LANG" = "en_EN.UTF-8")
> Sys.setenv("LC_CTYPE" = "en_EN.UTF-8")
> ```

**RStudio Preferences**

Preferences > Code > Saving > Default text encoding: UTF-8